# iOS 9.1 - Can't clear "documents & data" and "other" with restore - can it be done?

Tags: iphone, backup, restore, data, ios

I am trying to clear the 3+ GB of space occupied by other and documents and data on my iPhone 5S, running the new iOS 9.1 (13B5110e)

Usually I would do this by restoring the phone through iTunes and then restoring from a backup...but when I try that I get this message:

"Problem downloading software. Requested source was not found."

How can I clear these out in the version of iOS?

Comment: Discussion about what's on or off topic should be discussed in [chat] or on [meta]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29002/discussion-on-question-by-sizzle-ios-9-1-cant-clear-documents-data-and-o).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to "erase all content and settings" by using the settings app on the iPhone and then re-choose from the choices:

- restore from an iCloud backup
- restore from an iTunes backup
- set up as a new device
- restore from Android

The error message you mentioned is typically a result of not actually running iOS 9.1 on the device (or whatever build you were in the process of installing. You can verify the exact build of iOS on the phone from the settings app > general > about

It also could be that iTunes wants to see if it can get a newer OS than what it detects on the device. In that case, just put the device into recovery mode.

- Power off the phone
- Plug it into the Mac while holding the home button until you see the recovery screen

Comment: Thanks for the response. I mentioned the version and build in the post,  iOS 9.1 (13B5110e). I do not see an option to "erase all contents and settings." Isn't that what the restore does?

Comment: So - after erase all content - do you receive the prompt I mentioned?

Comment: ahhh...in the phone, not in iTunes. I have just erased. Will then try back yup

Comment: restore is in progress

Comment: i have restored the phone...everything seems to be okay, thus far. Thanks for the help.